# How to calculate checksum of XML header and body using sha-256 in java

Tags: java, jaxb, sha256, sha

I have a requirement to calculate checksum of the header and payload of the below XML using sha-256 and write it in the same XML at the trailer node(checksum element).
I have copied the source code in the below link.

[How to convert CSV to XML in Java using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637393/how-to-convert-csv-to-xml-in-java-using-jaxb/64977676#64977676)

I searched it in internet but could not find the solution I am looking for. Most of them are reading the  xml file from a physical location and converting it.
However I don't write the XML in a file(it's only for reference not for any other purpose). I need to calculate the checksum of header and payload, then write it in the trailer section on the go and send it over to Solace topic.

How do I calculate the checksum data of header and body of an XML using sha-256?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<canonMessage xmlns="http://www.test.com/canon/v1">
    <header>
        <metadata>
            <domain>
                <name>party</name>
                <schemaVersion>1.0</schemaVersion>
                <subdomain>
                    <name>employee</name>
                </subdomain>
            </domain>
            <identifier>
                <id idScheme="HRSystem/lanId">SHawking</id>
            </identifier>
            <source>HRSystem</source>
            <messageId>84ec00d0-2a33-11eb-ae59-0050569a5c1d</messageId>
        </metadata>
    </header>
    <payload>
        <employee xmlns="http://www.test.com/party/employee/v1">
            <employeeId>79498</employeeId>
            <lanId>SHawking</lanId>
            <name>
                <lastName>Hawking</lastName>
                <firstName>Steve</firstName>
            </name>
            <businessTitle>Client Manager</businessTitle>
            <status>A</status>
            <groupName>Management</groupName>
            <departmentName>Legal</departmentName>
            <costCentre>RUSYDFGLEG</costCentre>
            <officeLocation>Texas</officeLocation>
            <region>US</region>
        </employee>
    </payload>
    <auditRecords>
        <sourceAuditRecord>
            <system>HRSystem</system>
            <timestamp>
                <created>2020-11-19T17:50:32.84+11:00</created>
                <sent>2020-11-19T17:50:32.84+11:00</sent>
            </timestamp>
        </sourceAuditRecord>
    </auditRecords>
    <trailer>
        <checksum type="sha-256">f60875e4905b62ed188ca61aee75fcfe354ae57fba4cabc8aba093d86a001569</checksum>
    </trailer>
</canonMessage>
```

Answer (score 1):

## XML Digital Signature

The *Java XML Digital Signature API* is a standard Java API for generating and validating [XML Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature).

See [*XML Digital Signature API Overview and Tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-xml-digital-signature-api-overview-and-tutorial.htm)

The API is defined by [*JSR 105: XML Digital Signature APIs*](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=105).

The interface [`XMLSignature`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml.crypto/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignature.html) lets you sign and validate signatures.

Comment: This XML is not from the file. I generate the XML using JAXB and add checksum to it. The above is for an XML from the file. I marshal the java objects and get it as a string. What I need to do is to calculate the checksum data using DigestUtils.sha256Hex().
I tried passing the header and body java objects as string like this "DigestUtils.sha256Hex(xml.getHeaderdata().toString()+xml.getBody().toString())". However I am not sure if it is the right way to do

Comment: You can't hash the whole XML, because the XML also contains the hash. The signature is calculated with some elements only. And is not a good idea to hash the ".toString()".
The XML Crypto works using a XMLSignatureFactory, and the only documented factory is for DOM . For signing you need to marshal the JAXB and parse the output to obtain the dom Document and signit . For validate a similar thing. It will be nice to have a XMLSignatureFactory for JAXB.

Comment: Understood, however the existing system followed the same pattern of converting the XML to string and calculate the checksum between header and payload in our case. I have followed the same and calculated and it's accepted. Thanks for your valuable inputs